Rigify Error: Bone 'upper_arm.L': Input to rig type must be a chain of at least 3 bones

I got this error once I pressed Generate
RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'upper_arm.L': Input to rig type must be a chain of at least 3 bones.

Incorrect armature for type 'limb_rigs'
I was hoping someone was willing to help with this rig by trouble shooting the rig setup
This is the rig file
https://www.mediafire.com/file/jzffr0uir3e5jy2/Kxley.blend/file
I'm pretty new to 3d modeling


The bone which is preventing the generation is the thumb one, named forearm.001, which has to be separated from the arm chain (Edit mode, select it, Alt P > Disconnect bone).
There are many others errors in the setup:

Scale of the Metarig has to be applied (Ctrl A)
animation data have to be deleted before generating
model should face you when in front view
knee should be pushed forward a bit
feet are wrongly placed
every newly created bone which is alone or first in a chain should have a rig type assigned in Pose mode

Maybe you'd better watch some more tutorials about Rigify use.
